# How to wire up to events associated with VS2010's Outlining model

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm writing an extension for VS2010 that reorders a page of code by rearranging code sections and inserting #regions.

I want to be able to code in a call to the "Edit.CollapseToDefinitions" command after I've completed my text manipulations. I can invoke this command in the Visual Studio model by calling ExecuteCommand on my DTE2 object.

However, if I invoke the command immediately after moving my text around the document VS hasn't had time to update its outlining record. So, I want to be able to hook up to outlining events on the current Text Editor window. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no great way to do it.  You can listen for outlining region change events on the [IOutliningManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.outlining.ioutliningmanager.aspx) (retrieved by [Import]ing an [IOutliningManagerService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.outlining.ioutliningmanagerservice.aspx)), but there are no guarantees that the first event will be the one in which the language service re-introduces all the outlining regions it can.  Most languages do it on the VS idle loop, but still at some delay so that it doesn't interrupt slow typing.

I would try playing around with something like:

1. Complete your text edits
2. Call collapse to definitions
3. Subscribe to `IOutliningManager.RegionsChanged`
4. If the next event is raised in, say, the next 5 seconds, call collapse to definitions again.

Comment: Thanks Noah. That sounds pretty messy doesn't it?

Comment: It's the downside of the asynchronous model the languages use.  I'm hoping to introduce something in future versions of VS that'll let consumers ask for tags (including outlining regions) in such a way that means "and go ahead and block until you're ready".